# Allow access to webserver located in a LAN from remote server hosted at GoDaddy

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, reverse-proxy, tunneling, tunnel

I want to allow people to access a webserver located on acomputer in my LAN buy my ISP does not allow me to open any ports. I have a website hosted on a shared hosting that allows ssh access. Is there a way to tunnel via SSH and allow people to get into my LAN webserver from the shared hosting site? Both are ubuntu servers.

Answer (score 1):

Get a different professional ISP service that supports opening ports. An ISP that does not allow a http server is not going to be helpful troubleshooting remote access to your network.

Or host the web server remotely, not on your LAN. Many hosting providers to choose from.